# core-drag-drop and core-list: controlling x & y coords of avatar

Tags: drag-and-drop, polymer, dart-polymer

I've created a `core-list` which supports ordering items by drag and drop using `core-drag-drop` and it works.

However, what I want is to force the x coordinate of the dragging item to always be pinned to the left edge of the list. Similarly I don't want to allow the items to be dragged off the top or bottom of the list.

I can't figure out a way to do that with core-drag-drop as it seems hardwired to move the top left of the dragging item to the mouse coords.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You seem to get ahead on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225725/building-a-reorderable-list-via-dnd-using-core-list-and-core-drag-drop

Comment: I gave up trying to do this. Hopefully, when they add drag and drop support to core-list they add support for this (at least on mobile)