# building a reorderable list (via dnd) using core-list and core-drag-drop

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I'm trying to build a reusable polymer web component that supports reordering items via drag and drop in a core-list. The interface I want is essentially the same as core-list

```
<reorderable-list id="list" data="{{data}}" height="60">
  <template>
    <some-reorderable-element>
    </some-reorderable-element>
  </template>
</reorderable-list>
```

My current thinking is that I want each row to be wrapped as follows

```
<a-container>
    <draggable-member>
       <some-reorderable-element>
       </some-reorderable-element>
    </draggable-member>
</a-container>
```

where `a-container` always remains in place and is sized exactly the size of a row and `draggable-member` gets detached on drag from `a-container` and attached to the `core-drag-drop` avatar. As `a-container` remains in place this should keep the row there with just the background colour I'm hoping.

The part I'm struggling with is how to instantiate the above structure for each row.

I was heading down a path like

```
<core-list-dart id="list" data="{{data}}" height="{{height}}">
  <template>
    <a-container>
      <draggable-member id="member" draggable="true">
        <content></content>
      </draggable-member>
    </a-container>
  </template>
</core-list-dart>
```

Not sure if this is heading in the right direction. Catch is that `core-list` is only going to instantiate copies of `a-container`. Somehow I'd need to instantiate copies of `draggable-member` and the user provided content for each row too but not sure how best to do that or if this is even a good approach.

**Edit**

Well after pulling my hair out for a few hours I thought I had the answer by doing it programatically like

```
@CustomTag('reorderable-list')
class ReorderableList extends PolymerElement with Observable {
  @published ObservableList data;
  @published double height;


  ReorderableList.created() : super.created() {
  }

  attached() {
    final CoreList coreList = new Element.tag('core-list-dart');
    coreList.data = data;
    coreList.height = height;

    final TemplateElement template = new Element.tag('template');

    final MemberContainer mc = new Element.tag('member-container');
    final ReorderableMember rm = new Element.tag('reorderable-member');
    rm.children.addAll(children);
    mc.append(rm);
    template.content.append(mc);
    coreList.append(template);

    shadowRoot.append(coreList);
  }
}
```

This almost gives me what I want but not quite as I'm not putting things in the shadow dom. Back to the drawing board :-(

### Edit2

I thought I had it nailed but now it seems that the ContentElement behaves in mysterious ways.
When the row items are using `<content></content>` then this content disappears when you detach the component from it's usual parent and add it to the avatar. Presumably the ContentElement works dynamically and can no longer find the associated content. I'll have to get a better understanding of how that works to see if I can get around it.

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../../packages/core_elements/core_style.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../../packages/core_elements/core_drag_drop.html">

<core-style id="draggable-list-item" unresolved>
  #row-container, #drag-container {
    padding: none;
    margin: none;
    display: block;
  }

  #row-container {
    border: solid 1px black;
  }
}

</core-style>

<polymer-element name="draggable-list-item" on-drag-start="{{startDrag}}">
  <template>

    <core-style ref="draggable-list-item"></core-style>
    <core-drag-drop></core-drag-drop>

    <div id="row-container">
      <drag-container id="drag-container">
        <content></content>
      </drag-container>
    </div>

  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="draggable_list_item.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>


<polymer-element name="drag-container" draggable="true">
  <template>
    <style>
      #foo {
        border: solid 1px blue;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>

    <div id="foo">
      <p>Hola</p>
      <content></content>
    </div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

--

```
library ui.polymer.core.list.item.draggable;

import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:logging/logging.dart';
import 'dart:js';

Logger _log = new Logger('ui.polymer.core.item.draggable');


@CustomTag('draggable-list-item')
class DraggableListItem extends PolymerElement with Observable {
  bool multi;

  DraggableListItem.created() : super.created() {
    _log.finer('DraggableListItem.created');
  }
  void startDrag(CustomEvent e, JsObject dragInfo) {
    _log.finest('DraggableListItem dragging ${identityHashCode(e)} '
      '${e.target}, ${e.currentTarget}, ${e.detail}, ${dragInfo}');
    _log.finest('e.target == e.currentTarget => ${identical(e.target, e.currentTarget)}');
    final HtmlElement avatar = dragInfo['avatar'];

    final rect = getBoundingClientRect();

    avatar.style.setProperty('width', '${rect.width}px');
    avatar.style.setProperty('height', '${rect.height}px');

    final dragContainer = $['drag-container'];

    final rowContainer = $['row-container'];

    rowContainer.style.setProperty('width', '${rect.width}px');
    rowContainer.style.setProperty('height', '${rect.height}px');

    dragContainer.style.setProperty('width', '${rect.width}px');
    dragContainer.style.setProperty('height', '${rect.height}px');

    avatar.append(dragContainer.clone(true));
    dragContainer.style.display = 'none';
    dragInfo['drag'] = drag;
    dragInfo['drop'] = drop;
  }

  drag(JsObject dragInfo) {
    print('drag');
    final HtmlElement avatar = dragInfo['avatar'];
    print(avatar);
  }
  drop(JsObject dragInfo) {
    print('drop');
    final HtmlElement avatar = dragInfo['avatar'];
    print(avatar);
  }
}


@CustomTag('drag-container')
class DragContainer extends PolymerElement with Observable {
  bool multi;

  DragContainer.created() : super.created() {
    _log.finer('DragContainer.created');
    print('DragContainer.created');
  }
}
```

--

```
<core-list-dart height="100" data="{{data}}">
  <template>
    <draggable-list-item>
      <test-row></test-row>
    </draggable-list-item>
  </template>
</core-list-dart>
```

Comment: I didn't have a closer look what you are trying to do but your question/answer miss `super.attached();` which is necessary to do the actual inserting into the DOM.

Comment: It's not clear from your code if you are using `core-list-dart` or `reorderable-list`.

Comment: In the `<core-list-dart>` code snipped, where should the content for `<content>` come from. How would you like to use the element.

Comment: The content in `<core-list-dart>` should be the content of `<reorderable-list>`. The idea is that you use `reorderabe-list` like you would use `core-list` and it behaves the same except that you can drag the rows around to reorder them

Comment: The complication is that I am trying to in effect extend the template tree passed to `core-list-dart`. `core-list-dart` turns that template into a repeating template for each row of data. I want to wrap the row element that the user passes in with the `member-container` etc so I can layer in the dragging functionality

Comment: Ok, that helps to understand.

Comment: Yes `<reorderable-list>` is a replacement to `core-list-dart`. It uses `core-list-dart` as part of the implementation

Comment: Dis you try `super.attached()` yet? (as first line in `attached`)

Comment: I added it to my current code which is taking a very different approach. It didn't help there. I have abandoned the approach I added in the last edit as I think it is working at the wrong level. I need to change the template used to create the shadow doms, whereas the above simply added things to the light doms. It superficially looked like it worked until I started trying to do the drag n drop and realised it was broken

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62570/discussion-between-anders-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: This might be interesting to you too https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/issues/121#issuecomment-58080495

Comment: It's a while that I worked on dnd but as far as I remember I used a workaround - clone the element I wanted to use as an avatar, placed it outside the view `x=-1000`, `y=-1000` and then referenced it as drag image. Maybe this helps to avoid the problem you mentioned.

Comment: The positioning isn't true but I cloned the dragged element https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_datagrid/blob/master/lib/effects/sortable.dart#L169-169 but this example doesn't use HTML5 dnd. In another place I used HTML5 dnd but that is broken since a recent update and I couldn't find time to take a look.

Comment: Thanks Günter. I'm cloning the distributed nodes of the content https://bitbucket.org/andersmholmgren/ah_polymer_stuff/src/e7a8fa14734797b1f347d90837a84c08beb50567/lib/draggable_list_item.dart?at=master#cl-51. I need to understand how the content element behaves in order to understand why I lose the extra content

Comment: I changed tack today and implemented it with native html5 drag and drop support (instead of using the polymer `<core-drag-drop>` element).
It gets around the problem of the missing content which is nice. However, I've got a new problem which I've asked separately
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271903/preventing-the-contents-of-draggable-polymer-elements-from-being-selectable

Answer (score 1):

I got my attempt to wrap the `<core-list-dart>` working so far (without drag-n-drop).

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:core_elements/core_list_dart.dart';

@CustomTag('reorderable-list')

class ReorderableList extends PolymerElement {

  /// Constructor used to create instance of ReorderableList.
  ReorderableList.created() : super.created();

  @PublishedProperty(reflect: true)
  List<String> data;

  attached() {
    super.attached();
    var template = querySelector('template');
    var coreList = (shadowRoot.querySelector('core-list-dart') as CoreList);
    coreList.append(template);
  }
}
```

```dart
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/core_elements/core_list_dart.html">

<polymer-element name="reorderable-list">
  <template>
    <core-list-dart data="{{data}}"></core-list-dart>
    <content></content>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="reorderable_list.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

usage (basically the same as `<core-list-dart>`)

```dart
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/core_elements/core_list_dart.html">
<link rel="import" href="drag_container.html">
<link rel="import" href="draggable_member.html">
<link rel="import" href="test_element.html">
<link rel="import" href="reorderable_list.html">

<polymer-element name="app-element">
  <template>
    reorderable-list
    <reorderable-list data="{{strings}}">
      <template id="app-element-reorderable">
        <drag-container>
          <draggable-member id="member" draggable="true">
            <test-element>{{name}}</test-element>
          </draggable-member>
        </drag-container>
      </template>
    </reorderable-list>

  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="app_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

class Item {
  String name;
  Item(this.name);
  bool selected = false;

  String toString() => name;
}

@CustomTag('app-element')

class AppElement extends PolymerElement {

  @observable
  List strings = toObservable([new Item('Anton'), new Item('Berta'), new Item('Caesar'), new Item('Dora')]);

  AppElement.created() : super.created();
}
```

I think it should work when `<reorderable-list>` implements the drag-n-drop event handlers.

Comment: ah yes. Your solution is in between where I started and where I was trying to end up. I started with using `core-list` directly and building all the dnd into my own row element. That kinda worked but in order to get rid of the last glitch I realised it was easier to go for something more generic. So I tried to build a drop in replacement for `core-list` but as your answer points out, what I'm better off doing is simply creating a draggable-wrapper for the rows. In fact I don't think I need the `reorderable-list` at all. I should be able to do it with a normal `core-list`. Try that tomorrow. ty

Comment: I was thinking of `reorderable-list` as one place to listen for and handle dnd events but when your wrapper is a polymer element you have basically the same. I guess you would need a reference to `core-list-dart` from within the wrapper to be able to add/remove items.

Comment: BTW I unticked this answer as I'm confident this solution would run into the same problem during drag. i.e. need to do the trick with `content.getDistributedNodes()`

Answer (score 0):

I've added all this code to https://bitbucket.org/andersmholmgren/ah_polymer_stuff. Everyone is free to make use of this.

I'm very close now. It is working in that I can move rows around.

The last obstacle is that I'm losing part of the row contents in the avatar during drag. I'm pretty sure it comes from my last trick.

The element is now defined as

```
<polymer-element name="draggable-list-item" on-drag-start="{{startDrag}}">
  <template>

    <core-style ref="draggable-list-item"></core-style>
    <core-drag-drop></core-drag-drop>

    <div id="row-container">
      <div id="drag-container">
        <content></content>
      </div>
    </div>

  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="draggable_list_item.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

and you use it like

```
<core-list-dart height="100" data="{{data}}">
  <template>
    <draggable-list-item>
      <test-row data="{{self}}"></test-row>
    </draggable-list-item>
  </template>
</core-list-dart>
```

where test-row looks like

```
<polymer-element name="test-row"  unresolved>
  <template>
    <h1>hello I'm a row {{data}}</h1>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

So the test row (`<test-row data="{{self}}"></test-row>`) is what ends up as the content in

```
<div id="row-container">
  <div id="drag-container">
    <content></content>
  </div>
</div>
```

As I mentioned earlier ContentElement behaves in mysterious ways. In order to get it to render properly I did the following

```
final dragContainer = $['drag-container'];

final ContentElement content = dragContainer.querySelector('content');
print(content.getDistributedNodes());
final dragDiv = new Element.tag('div');
final clonedNodes = content.getDistributedNodes().map((n) =>
    n.clone(true));
clonedNodes.forEach((n) {
  dragDiv.append(n);
});

dragDiv.style.width = '${rect.width}px';
dragDiv.style.height = '${rect.height}px';
dragDiv.style.border = "solid blue 1px";

avatar.append(dragDiv);
dragContainer.style.display = 'none';
```

I had to get and clone the distributed nodes of the content. This works fine except my suspicion is that this is also why I lose part of the row on drag.

Normally the rows render as

```
hello I'm a row data item null with value 2
```

the `data item null with value 2` part comes from the toString of the data class I'm using.

On drag that part disappears and all that displays is

```
hello I'm a row
```

Somewhere along the line that part disappears and I'm not sure how to fix it

Sadly this only works in dartium. In chrome when you drag the avatar seems to just stay top left and never moves. I suspect this might just be a big in the core_drag_drop in dart.