# Preventing the contents of draggable polymer elements from being selectable

Tags: polymer, dart-polymer

I have a polymer element defined as follows

```
<polymer-element name="draggable-list-item" >
  <template>

    <core-style ref="draggable-list-item"></core-style>

    <div id="row-container" draggable="true">
      <content></content>
    </div>

  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="draggable_list_item.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

I know that for normal elements (non polymer / web component) that I need to add a style like

```
  [draggable] {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
```

And everything is awesome

I can't get this to work with polymer. I can drag the item if I select it outside of the contents of the child polymer element. But not over it. I've tried various variants of

```
  [draggable]  /deep/ * {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
```

but nothing seems to work

Comment: where is the CSS placed? In my opinion it should be inside the `<template>`.

Comment: I'm using `<core-style>`. I just tried putting it directly in the template but made no difference

Comment: I haven't used core-style yet and don't know how it works.

Comment: Ignoring core-style is `[draggable]  /deep/ * {` the correct selector?

Comment: Can you try `[draggable], [draggable]::content *, [draggable]::content /deep/ * {`

Comment: Still doesn't work. I've set up a simple demonstration (https://bitbucket.org/andersmholmgren/ah_polymer_stuff/src/7f88d253fe98428e280c1fa4aceada1792a686e1/test/demo/?at=master). I've taken https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-samples/tree/master/html5/web/dnd/basics and made two forms. One the same as the original (index.html) and one using polymer (index_poly.html).
It shows the problem quite clearly. You can drag on the header in the original version but not the polymer one

Comment: I think my selector example sucks, but I have never used `::content` yet. I don't have time today but I'll have a look as soon as I find time.

Comment: I was not yet able to reproduce the problem. I commented out all `-x-user-select` and tried `/ah_polymer_stuff/test/reorderable_list.html` but I still can't select text. Dragging also only works when I start dragging outside of the text. Update: I just removed `="true"` from the `draggable` attribute and now I can select the text. I'm using Dartium Version 38.0.2125.0 (292247) (64-bit).

Comment: Sorry I have misled you. It's not selecting the text that is the issue. It's that you can't drag when you are over the text. If you look in `/ah_polymer_stuff/test/demo` you can see the problem clearly. `index.html` is the original [native dnd](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-samples/tree/master/html5/web/dnd/basics) example where you can drag when over the text. `index_poly.html` is the same thing but where the contents is now in a polymer element. Here you can't drag when over the text

Comment: Ok, I got it. I'll have another look tomorrow.